# A decent S3 bucket manager for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a **decent** S3 bucket manager for Ubuntu (Gnome). I prefer it to integrate with Nautilus so it will look like just any other drive (a la WebDAV) but so far I haven't been able to find anything that I'd like to use on a daily basis.

What bucket managers do you use for Ubuntu or what bucket manager would you recommend?

**UPDATE:**

S3FS seems to be what I'd really want to use since it lets me integrate my buckets directly into my file-system. However, when trying S3FS I do not get the impression that it's ready for prime time.

I'm stunned by the fact that there are no decent bucket managers out there for Ubuntu/Gnome, guess I have to build it myself...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279213/best-amazon-s3-file-manager-utility

Comment: "when trying S3FS I do not get the impression that it's ready for prime time." What gave you that impression?

Comment: @joe the link is dead: This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. :-/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why a separate file manager when there is [**s3fs**](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), which makes it possible to mount S3 buckets via fuse?

That way you won't notice any difference between local files and your S3 bucket in nautilus.

Comment: I've looked at this in the past and couldn't get it to work back then.  If it would work it would be totally what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question like "Why doesn't s3fs work?" ;)

Comment: @Kim: Maybe. I was wondering if there where other 'decent' S3 managers available for Ubuntu before trying s3fs again. Guess not....

Comment: Why isn't s3fs in Ubuntu repos?

Comment: @Kim it looks like this hasn't made it into the Ubuntu packages. There is an old project for the Lucid distro on Launchpad. Am I to conclude from this that in the 2.5 years since your answer, something else has become more popular?

Comment: _"That way you won't notice any difference between local files and your S3 bucket in nautilus."_
I've noticed it right away, it's painfully slow, that's why I decided not to use it.

Comment: Why a separate file manager? To perform parallel upload/download because s3fs is pathologically slow. It does not utilize multiple connections and uploads files one after another.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR [CrossFTP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/crossftp/) is in the Ubuntu app store, you must "buy" it for the purchase price of $0.00. So an Ubuntu One account is required, to install that way. For a mountable file-system try [S3QL, which is available through a PPA](https://code.google.com/p/s3ql/wiki/installation_ubuntu).

Okay, it seems part of the confusion with s3fs is that there are THREE of them with mostly the same name with varying levels of development and stability. However, S3QL appears ready to go and slick. Another one worth checking out is s3backer.

For a GUI, I'm using CrossFTP. I've also installed dragondisk, but I personally need to access a custom (Dreamhost Objects) S3 server (non-amazon). S3QL will do that for you as well as CrossFTP. WARNING: CrossFTP is "open-core" software, though it is worth it!

Three similar packages that you shouldn't worry about (development has mostly stopped on all but the one noted)

- FuseOverAmazon (previously s3fs)
- s3fs-fuse
- s3fs
- s3fs

Wouldn't it be nice if that list was full of links so you knew what the heck I was talking about? Well, stackexchange won't let me post more than 2 links because I don't have enough rep points. How am I supposed to get them if I cannot be informative? :( The TL;DR part is the most important. You can look up open-core in wikipedia, another link I wasn't allowed to post!

Comment: Thanks for the up vote! One more and I'm allowed to up vote this question.

Answer (score 6):

DragonDisk is a decent Amazon S3 GUI client for Ubuntu.

Comment: DragonDisk is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4):

Use [s3cmd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/s3cmd.1.html) which has a sync command to transfer files either direction.

Comment: is this meaningfully different from the aws cli suite?

Answer (score 0):

[S3fm](http://www.s3fm.com/) - free online Amazon S3 File Manager.

Comment: The link is dead.